# build R package with C code (without Rcpp)

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, r, package

> environment：
>
> - OS：Windows10 [10.0.14393]
> - R：3.4.1 (2017-06-30) -- "Single Candle" 32-bit
> - Rstudio：1.0.143
> - Rtools：3.4.0.1964

This is my first time to build R package (named `testt`).
I'm trying to build a package with some C code without using `Rcpp`.
I have put all .c files (called `lca.c`, `rlca_cond.c`, `rlca_prev.c`and `rlca_condprev.c`)
and their header file in `/src`.

And I have some C function defined in `chanmat.c`, declared in `chanmat.h`.
`chanmat.c` and `chanmat.h` are also in `/src`.
Both `lca.h`, `rlca_cond.h`, `rlca_prev.h` and `rlca_condprev.h` have `#include 'chanmat.h'`.

In `chanmat.h`, I use the following to prevent multiple definition when compiling.

```
#ifndef CHANMATH_H
#define CHANMATH_H
...
#endif
```

I have also used following in NAMESPACE file (generated by `roxygen2`)

```
useDynLib(testt,lca)
useDynLib(testt,rlca_cond)
useDynLib(testt,rlca_prev)
useDynLib(testt,rlca_condprev)
useDynLib(testt,chanmat)
```

When I run build & reload, I got following error

```
Updating testt documentation
Loading testt
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  no such symbol chanmat in package 
C:/Users/elephant/Desktop/project/testt/src/testt.dll
Calls: suppressPackageStartupMessages ... assignNativeRoutines -> 
getNativeSymbolInfo -> lapply -> FUN
��������

Exited with status 1.
```

I have no idea why `chanmat.c`/`chanmat.h` are failed to compile.
This question bothers me for a long time.
Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: Have you set the `NeedsCompilation` flag in the DESCRIPTION file?

Comment: Yes I did. 
Will DESCRIPTION file affect compilation?